# White space on right of screen for horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue on my [website](http://memara.myweb.usf.edu/) where upon zooming in until the horizontal scroll-bar appears, if I were to scroll to the right, I'd find blank space with my mock-up hovering over it. I'm trying to figure out a way to extend the background of my divs just as my navbar does so that it always covers this blank space up. I wish to allow side-scrolling if someone were to zoom in, so I have my body's overflow set to auto. Setting body width to 100% does not seem to fix this problem.

I understand that this might be difficult to answer without the powering html and css. If requested, I'll clean it up (its a bit messy) and post it.

To be a little more specific, whenever I have a horizontal scroll bar (whether its from zooming or simply reducing screen width by dragging), if I scroll enough to the right I find white space. How could I allow my div backgrounds to fit that space?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: add this to your css file  *{ margin:0; padding:0; } it works.!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`! By the way, when I open your website weather on a small screen laptop or full hd which is 1920 on 1080 I do not see any white spaces on a right side. The only white space I see it when I zoom out to 50% in `Chrome` on the bottom!!!

Comment: Already have this, thanks though. And the white space appears when you zoom in far enough to see the horizontal scroll-bar and scroll to the very right.

Comment: Most likely it was overridden somewhere. Could you please mention the name of the `css` where you are doing a manipulation with background size?

Comment: g-nee.css has the majority of any edits I have done for css.

Comment: Here is a quick solution `#fitwid {
        overflow-x: hidden; 
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the CSS to your body, this is an issue with your padding:

```
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and didn't get any effect out of it unfortunately (even after setting each to !imporant). Could some of my padding/margins be overriding this?

Comment: Maybe add this to all of the divs that have padding. @Modrummer

Answer (score 0):

Add the css on your jumbotron:

```
background-color: /*#4ABDAC #FC4A1A #3CC47C #F7C331 #57BC90 #438496 #88D317*/ #73B66B !important;
```

to your body.

Comment: This doesn't really do much except add that color to my entire page, meaning wherever I had whitespace, I now have that color.

Comment: @Modrummer Oh. I thought that was the whole page.